# Custom settings with PHP on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have multiple websites setup using Nginx and Apache, but when I try to add a vhost based PHP directive using  fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE , the value get added to all of my vhosts. Checking the value of the PHP parameter from PHP-CLI remain the actual one for whole server. e.g.

I used fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=512M" for a domain based nginx config, but it will be propagated to all domains on server. The 'php -i | grep memory_limit' show 128M though

Not sure what I am missing

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `nginx.conf` and vhost configuration files the diagnose the issue. You can obfuscate domains and IPs if you feel you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse php-cli with PHP.

`php -i | grep memory_limit` is not the same as `<?php phpinfo();` . Its very likely they use different php.ini files.

For your actual issue, where are you defining the value, in the common fcgi_params file or setting explicitly in each vhost location directive.

Comment: I know that php.ini used for PHP-CLI and PHP-GUI can be different. I have added the fatsci_param under vhost location directive.